# Laravel 8: How to properly return notifications on blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 to develop my project which is an Online Forum and for this project I wanted to add some notification feature that can alert the user if someone has answered a question that he had asked on the forum.

So basically, when someone answers a question, this method will run:

```
public function postAnswer(Question $id)
{
    $validate_data = Validator::make(request()->all(),[
        'answer' => 'required',
    ])->validated();

    $answer = Answer::create([
        'answer' => $validate_data['answer'],
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
        'question_id' => $id,
    ]);

    auth()->user()->notify(new RepliedToThread($id)); // making new notification

    return back();
}
```

Then, I created this notification called `RepliedToThread.php`:

```
class RepliedToThread extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    protected $thread;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($id)
    {
        $this->thread = $id;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'thread' => $this->thread,
            'user' => $notifiable
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

As you can see I have defined a protected variable called `$thread` and it is assigned to the `$id` variable which is comming from: `auth()->user()->notify(new RepliedToThread($id));`

After that, I tried returning them by:

```
public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'thread' => $this->thread,
            'user' => $notifiable
        ];
    }
```

And finally, I added this to the blade:

```
<a href="">
   {{$notification->data['thread']['title']}}</strong>
</a>
```

But now I get this error:

> ErrorException **Undefined index: thread**

So I don't really know what is going wrong here! So if you know how to solve this, please let me know, I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Here is also my table `notifications`, if you would like to look:

[image]

And this is also the result of `{{ dd($notification) }}` on blade:

[image]

Comment: So you wanna push the notification via real-time?

Comment: @WailanTirajoh Yes, but for now I get this error!

Comment: well let me answer this on answer post, basically for push notification you should use event

Comment: @WailanTirajoh I would really appreciate that ...

Comment: do you mean real time notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, your error caused by there's no *'thread'* on the other notifications database. **how can you prevent that?** just add maybe a ***type*** to tell the difference notification view, and you need to tell every other notification with a type name for maybe other *hasPost*, *createSome* or other.

```
public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'thread' => $this->thread,
            'user' => $notifiable,
            'type' => 'RepliedThread'
        ];
    }
```

and then in your notification blade you just use `if statement` to check what type is that

```
@forelse(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications as $notification)
@if($notification->data['type'] == "RepliedThread")
  <a href="">
   {{$notification->data['thread']['title']}}</strong>
</a>
@endif
@empty
no notification
@endforelse
```

And for the ***real-time notification*** you need to use **WebSockets Server**, there's a 3rd party for that and its called **Pusher** or if you want to use your own WebSocket server, Laravel has **`Laravel-Websockets`**. If you dig deeper into that you will find `Laravel-Echo`

Comment: But now I get `Undefined index: type` !

Comment: You need to add type to every other notification database also, so that your app know whats the type, and what to show.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by *every other notification database*, I have already `type` column at `notifications` table, just like the image shows...

Comment: the first 3 data has no data['thread'] that's causing error Undefined index error, cause they have no thread.